# The flexbox footer div does not display

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I'm trying to make a design with Flexbox.

I'm trying to make a 5 row design.

Google Chrome desktop version is fine. (79.0.3945.88 (64 bit))

Mobile:
Firefox for Android 68.3.0 also works correctly.

But:
(#Menubar, #statusbar) does not appear in Mobile Google Chrome 79.0.3945.79 for Android Iframe takes up all the space. But if I scroll down, I can see.

[My Css and Html Code](https://jsfiddle.net/omerx/hq2y6nx4/1/)

HTML

```
    <div id="page">
    <div id="titlebar">
        <span>Title Bar</span>
        <i class="fas fa-camera fa-xs"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-camera fa-sm"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-camera" id='filter' @click="isGizle = !isGizle"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="filterbar" :class="{gizle:isGizle}">
        Filtre Bar

    </div>
    <div id="toolbar">Tool Bar</div>
    <iframe id='content' class="FrameKalem" src="https://www.tcmb.gov.tr">FrameKalem</iframe>
    <div id="menubar">Menü Bar</div>
    <div id="statusbar">
        <span>Status Bar</span>
        <i class='fa fa-list' aria-hidden='true'></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
        html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #page {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
        justify-content: baseline;
    }

    #titlebar {
        background-color: #2ecc71;
        height: 1rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    #filterbar {
        background-color: khaki;
        min-height: 3rem;
    }

    #toolbar {
        background-color: #3498db;
        height: 2rem;
    }

    #content {
        flex-grow: 1;
        border: 0px;
        min-height: 1rem;
    }

    #menubar {
        background-color: darkorange;
        height: 2rem;
    }

    #statusbar {
        background-color: hotpink;
        height: 1rem;
    }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce,I can scroll all the way down and see everything, on both `79.0.3904.xx` and new version `79.0.3945.93`

Comment: Hello, I would like to display it without scrolling below.  Seamlessly with "grid-template". "flex" has more browser support, but I think I will use it. Sample: https://codepen.io/omerix/full/JjoNdQX

Comment: I think i understand now, what you're facing is the normal behavior of the chrome browser for android, when you scroll down enough it push up the toolbar that holds the `url` and such.